# Составное условие для SQLite в Android Studio

Tags: android, java, sqlite, android-studio

Сейчас мой код ищет записи по признаку `KEY_ADS_VISITED == 0`:

```
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(0) };
    Cursor cursor = sqdb.query(TABLE_NAME_ADS, new String[] {
                    UID,
                    KEY_ADS_CATEGORY,
                    KEY_ADS_VISITED,},
            KEY_ADS_VISITED+" = ?", // The columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs, // The values for the WHERE clause
            null, // don't group the rows
            null, // don't filter by row groups
            null // The sort order
    );
```

Мне нужно добавить еще одно условие (чтобы `KEY_ADS_CATEGORY == idcat`).

Как сделать составное условие через "И"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(0), String.valueOf(idcat) };
Cursor cursor = sqdb.query(TABLE_NAME_ADS, new String[] {
                UID,
                KEY_ADS_CATEGORY,
                KEY_ADS_VISITED,},
        KEY_ADS_VISITED+" = ? AND " + KEY_ADS_CATEGORY + " = ?", // The columns for the WHERE clause
        selectionArgs, // The values for the WHERE clause
        null, // don't group the rows
        null, // don't filter by row groups
        null // The sort order
);
```

**Обновление**

`selectionArgs` - массив аргументов для условия `WHERE`, вместо каждого знака `?` будет подставляться соответствующее значение из массива.